# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at add.js:1

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am trying to get set up on a simple Electron project, but am having trouble resolving this issue. I have a file `add.js` that is used to add an event listener to a button to close a frameless browser window. I have the `add.js` file imported in a script tag to the HTML like so:

```
 <script src="add.js"></script>
```

The `add.js` file only contains this event listener:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const remote = electron.remote
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn')

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
})
```

If it is needed, here is `index.js`, the click event listener to open this window:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn');

notifyBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'add.html')
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        frame: false,
        transparent: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 200
    })
    win.loadURL(modalPath)
    win.show()
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('close', () => win = null)
})
```

The problem that I am having is that the frameless browser window opens just fine, but I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError:" immediately and the JS code does not load.

I've tried looking up the issue on here (stackoverflow) but the answers suggest that this is caused by attempting to run a node program in the browser. However, the `index.js` code that I included above works just fine, with no errors.

---

Here is the code to the HTML files as well, just in case I'm going crazy:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>BTCAlert</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="price-container">
        <p class="subtext">Current BTC USD</p>
        <h1 id="price">Loading..</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="goal-container">
        <p><img src="../assets/images/up.svg"><span id="targetPrice">Choose a Target Price</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
        <button id="notifyBtn">Notify Me When...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

`add.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/add.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="notify">Notify me when BTC reaches..</p>

        <div class="row2">
            <div>
                <input id="notifyVal" placeholder="USD">
            </div>
            <button id="updateBtn">Update</button>
        </div>

        <a id="closeBtn">Close Window</a><br>

        </div>
        <script src="add.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `require()` doesn't work when run in the context of a browser (whereas it runs fine in NodeJS context, or when bundling via tools like webpack).

Comment: @arthurakay I must be missing something then, the ```index.js``` file uses the require() function and works just fine.

Comment: `add.html` loads `add.js` which uses `require()` -- that's where the error is being thrown. It's been a while since I've used Electron, but I remember it having a hybrid-environment in certain contexts. Your frameless browser window (`app.html`) is a web-only context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
},
```

to the new BrowserWindow instance fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The require() function it can not be used in the client side....
Anywhere if u want to use it in client side you should look into [require.js](https://requirejs.org) or [head.js](https://github.com/headjs/headjs) for this.

Comment: I must be missing something then, the ```index.js``` file uses the require() function and works just fine.

Comment: I don't think I follow

Comment: You can take a look to this framework too browserify http://browserify.org/ it have the same utility... good luck

Comment: OP is talking about Electron apps, not regular web apps that run in a normal browser where this would be the case. See Revircs answer for the Electron version